# I cannot retrieve session value stored in first php page?

Tags: php, html

I stored a value of id in first php page as,

```
<?php

  ...
 $_SESSION["UID"] = $row["JS_ID"];
...

?>
```

this is the 2nd page,

```
<?php

  ...
 session_start(); 
$uid=$_SESSION["UID"];
...

?>
```

when am passing it as value it works,,but when I'm running my project, it's saying error as,
"Undefined index UID"..Is there any way to clear it out?

Comment: Do you have `session_start()` in your first page? If not, your session isn't established and your variable will be lost.

Comment: Do `print_r($_SESSION)` and temme what is your output..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these:

Page1.php:

```
<?php

...
session_start(); 
$_SESSION["UID"] = $row["JS_ID"];
...

?>
```

Page2.php:

```
<?php

...
session_start(); 
$uid=$_SESSION["UID"];
...

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to remove the session start from second page and start the session on that **first page** with

```
session_start();
```

Because whenever you have started the session then only you can access the session variables.But You are starting the session on the second page.Which has no use.

Comment: And remove the session_start on second page